# Difference between @Html.Display() and @Html.DisplayText()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

What is the exact difference between @Html.Display() and @Html.DisplayText()? Both are giving the same output.
I have a model class Employee which has a property

```
Name = "my Name".
```

And I am using Html helper in following way -

```
@Html.Display("Name")
@Html.DisplayText("Name")
```

The output for both methods is "my Name"

Comment: Take a look at arguments of both the methods. DisplayText() only have expression as argument where as Display() have other parameters too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inspect the source code for [Display](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/DisplayExtensions.cs) and [DisplayText](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/DisplayTextExtensions.cs).

`@Html.DisplayText(propertyName)` will only output the the value of the property (defined by the `SimpleDisplayText` of `ModelMetadata`).

`@Html.Display(propertyName)` provides far more options. If you have provided a `DisplayTemplate` from the property type, it will use the html in that template by default. You can also specify a specific template name to be used to generate the html. In additional, you can use the `additionalViewData` parameter of `Display()` to pass additional information to the template.

In your case, you property is `string` and you have not defined a `DisplayTemplate` for `string`, therefore `Display()` uses the default (in-built) template which generates the same output as `DisplayText()`